# How to prevent passing props to inner styled component

Tags: typescript, material-ui, emotion

I'm trying to make a composition on top of the material UI components changing only the style via given props.

```
import { Typography } from "@mui/material";
import { styled } from "@mui/system";

type MyTypographyExtraProps = { isEven?: boolean };

export const MyTypography = styled(Typography)<MyTypographyExtraProps>(
  ({ theme, isEven }) => `
   color: ${theme.palette.common.black};

   ::after {
      content: "";
      display: inline-block;
      height: ${theme.spacing(2)};
      width: ${theme.spacing(2)};
      border-radius: ${theme.spacing(2)};
      background-color: ${theme.palette[isEven ? "success" : "error"].main};
   }
  `,
);
```

The styled function passed my `isEven` props to the Material Typography component, and Typography passes it to DOM, so I get the warning

> Warning: React does not recognize the `isEven` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `iseven` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.

How can I omit the type before getting passed to the typography element?

I can make another component and eliminate the props in that layer, but I'm curious to know is there any way to do it without an extra component.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Material [docs](https://mui.com/customization/how-to-customize/#3-dynamic-variation) suggest a function to eliminate props from being passed.

**shouldForwardProp**: Say what props must be passed down to styled given components.

```
export const MyTypography = styled(MuiTypography, {
  shouldForwardProp: prop => prop !== "isEven", // ⭐
})<MyTypographyExtraProps>(
  ({ theme, isEven }) => `
   color: ${theme.palette.common.black};

   ::after {
      content: "";
      display: inline-block;
      height: ${theme.spacing(2)};
      width: ${theme.spacing(2)};
      border-radius: ${theme.spacing(2)};
      background-color: ${theme.palette[isEven ? "success" : "error"].main};
   }
  `,
);
```

**NOTE**: `shouldForwardProps` and `skipSx` props are not perfectly aligned if your you want to prevent `sx` and other props simultaneously.
For more info see [this github issue](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/31019)